# CSS tiles size tweak

Tags: css

i am trying to make my tiles look the same even text inside increase.but it does seems to be able to work even with word property.i want to make the "buy extended warranty" and ""List machines for service pack" to be same as others.
Anyone can help?
[image]

```
.tile {

width: 100%;
display: inline-block;
box-sizing: border-box;
background: #fff;
padding: 30px;
margin-bottom: 40px;
text-align:center;
```

}

```
.tile:hover
{
background:#F8F9F9;
}



    <div class="tab-pane active" id="warranty">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <a class="tile" style="background-color:#EBDEF0;" href="#">Show warranty </a>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <a class="tile" style="background-color:#EBDEF0;" href="#">New Warranty</a>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4 ">
                                        <a class="tile" style="background-color:#EBDEF0;" href="#">Delete Warranty</a>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4 ">
                                        <a class="tile " style="background-color:#EBDEF0;" href="#">Enter Invoice</a>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4 ">
                                        <a class="tile" style="background-color:#EBDEF0;" href="#">Enter Serial </a>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <a class="tile" style="background-color:#EBDEF0;" href="#">Buy extended warranty </a>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4 ">
                                        <a class="tile" style="background-color:#EBDEF0;" href="#">List Machines for service pack</a>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Comment: Do you want all the divs to be the same height or just have the same width and margins?

Comment: same width and height as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `flex-box` for this:

css:

```
.tab-pane {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.tile {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}

.tile:hover {
    background: #F8F9F9 !important;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="warranty">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <a class="tile" style="background-color:#EBDEF0;" href="#">Show warranty </a>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <a class="tile" style="background-color:#EBDEF0;" href="#">New Warranty</a>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 ">
        <a class="tile" style="background-color:#EBDEF0;" href="#">Delete Warranty</a>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 ">
        <a class="tile " style="background-color:#EBDEF0;" href="#">Enter Invoice</a>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 ">
        <a class="tile" style="background-color:#EBDEF0;" href="#">Enter Serial </a>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <a class="tile" style="background-color:#EBDEF0;" href="#">Buy extended warranty </a>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 ">
        <a class="tile" style="background-color:#EBDEF0;" href="#">List Machines for service pack</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

I adjusted the class on your `col-md-4` to `col-sm-4` so you could see it in action. I included the bootstrap CDN CSS, as you are using bootstrap class names in your HTML. And I added `!important` to override your inline color styles on the anchor tags.

Here's the fiddle to see it in action:
https://jsfiddle.net/mjqfjbh0/1/

Comment: it still look the same at my side even i clear cache and refresh browser. and tab-pane will not work if i change the display to flex.

Comment: @MVCnewbie then you need to wrap the `.col-sm-4` in another wrapper and put the `flex` property on that. What browser are you using? You may need to add the browser prefixes to the `display: flex`.

Comment: i am using chrome but your jsfiddle looks fine to me.i add another `div` and include the`flex` class. it also does not change anything. i copy paste your code also the same.strange

Comment: @MVCnewbie Are you including the bootstrap css in your document? That's the only thing I can think of...